# Phpmyadmin error 2002 with nginx

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, redhat

I have installed phpmyadmin on my web server. When I go to the link http://phpmyadmin.domainname.com, I get a "#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)."

Mysql is on another server and on the same network. the config.inc.php pints to the database server IP w/ the root password.

I can log in using a mysql username and pswd, but get error right away.

PHP version: 5.3.3 - PHPmyadmin version:3.5.8.2
Using Nginx. 
Red Hat 6.4

Comment: The error says it all - you're trying to connect to a **LOCAL** unix-domain socket, not your "on another server" mysql instance.

Comment: I thought that's what it was. I tried this article, but cannot get rid of error. http://www.danielmois.com/article/Manage_remote_databases_from_localhost_with_phpMyAdmin Any recommendations?